# Combining two data frame date columns into one column - in order

Tags: r, dataframe, date, lubridate, rbind

My temperature data had missing values that I needed to fill in, however when I went to rbind the new Date values from the newly made dataframe of missing dates, it ended up on the bottom of the combined data frame, out of order. How do I get R to understand to sift these into the spots they belong?

Example:

```
df1 
2022-01-01
2022-01-02
2022-01-05
2022-01-06

df2
2022-01-03
2022-01-04

CombinedDf
2022-01-01
2022-01-02
2022-01-05
2022-01-06
2022-01-03
2022-01-04
```

But the Combined is out of order, this is how I would like it to look

```
CombinedDf
2022-01-01
2022-01-02
2022-01-03
2022-01-04
2022-01-05
2022-01-06
```

There are other values and other things going on in the df, but this is just for illustration of my problem.

I converted both columns into dates from characters.

Then I used rbind to combine the two separate columns into a combined column.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options. Here's some sample data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(dates = as.Date(c("2022-01-01", 
                                    "2022-01-02", 
                                    "2022-01-05",
                                    "2022-01-06")),
                  foo = c(1:4))

df2 <- data.frame(dates = as.Date(c("2022-01-03", 
                                    "2022-01-04")),
                  foo = c(5:6))
```

Using `rbind()` and `order()`:

```
df3 <- rbind(df1, df2)
df3 <- df3[order(df3$dates, decreasing = FALSE),] # ascending
df3 <- df3[order(df3$dates, decreasing = TRUE),] # descending
```

Technically you don't need "decreasing = FALSE" to get the result you want as this is the default.

Or you can do it in one step with the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)

df3 <- bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% 
  arrange(dates) # ascending

df3 <- bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% 
  arrange(desc(dates)) # descending
```